# What's the difference between operator and index in rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

While searching for operators, I'm getting two options but not clearly stated in documentation about what it is. Please find reference image.

Official site: https://rxjs.dev/api?query=combine

[image]

Comment: index is just referring to the general search index in which all terms are included.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton no not everything comes under index, search keywords `ajax`, `webSocket`